# Пронумеровать строки, хранящиеся в переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строки, которые хранятся в переменной(title_book_risc):

```
['влияние организации движения соединенныхгрузовых поездов на повышение пропускной способности участков, электрифицированных на постоянном токе']
['влияние особенностей размещения населения на развитие всм в европе']
['влияние перекоса колесных пар на снижение их жизненного цикла при движении электровоза в криволинейном участке рельсового пути']
['выбор технологии восстановления работоспособности узлов подвижного состава с учетом минимума затрат при условии обеспечения требуемого уровня надежности']
['гравиметрические особенности размещения населения в пределах большого урала']
```

Пытаюсь их пронумеровать:

```
for i in enumerate(title_book_risc):
    print(i)
```

Но получается не так, как мне нужно:

```
(0, 'влияние организации движения соединенныхгрузовых поездов на повышение пропускной способности участков, электрифицированных на постоянном токе')
(0, 'влияние особенностей размещения населения на развитие всм в европе')
(0, 'влияние перекоса колесных пар на снижение их жизненного цикла при движении электровоза в криволинейном участке рельсового пути')
(0, 'выбор технологии восстановления работоспособности узлов подвижного состава с учетом минимума затрат при условии обеспечения требуемого уровня надежности')
(0, 'гравиметрические особенности размещения населения в пределах большого урала')
```

Желаемый результат:

```
1['влияние организации движения соединенныхгрузовых поездов на повышение пропускной способности участков, электрифицированных на постоянном токе']
2['влияние особенностей размещения населения на развитие всм в европе']
3['влияние перекоса колесных пар на снижение их жизненного цикла при движении электровоза в криволинейном участке рельсового пути']
4['выбор технологии восстановления работоспособности узлов подвижного состава с учетом минимума затрат при условии обеспечения требуемого уровня надежности']
5['гравиметрические особенности размещения населения в пределах большого урала']
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как достичь такого итога?

Comment: У вас в `title_book_risc` хранится список списков, каждый из которых содержит только один строковый элемент?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev,да, хранится список списков и, да, только один строковый элемент

Comment: Ваша проблема не воспроизводится https://ideone.com/Qa7ZB6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in enumerate(title_book_risc):
    print(*i)
```

Comment: Если нужно прямо как в желаемой результате, то: `print(*i, sep="")` :)

Comment: @gil9red, благодарю за комментарий. А если я хочу, чтобы отсчёт начинался с 1, а не с 0?

Comment: @Ireen1985, тогда так: `enumerate(title_book_risc, 1):`

Comment: @gil9red, благодарю!!!